# Redirect URIs vs Reply URL

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Why does the Azure portal use "Redirect URIs" and "Reply URL" when referring to the same?  Shouldn't it be consistent?  They are the same thing, right?

[image: portal screenshot]

Comment: Yes, they are inconsistent and yes, they are referring to the same URI/Ls.

Comment: I think it should be a Product issue. they're different concept but they have same meanings there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in the context you are describing Reply URLs and Redirect URIs are the same thing. This is why the reply URL in the app registration needs to match the Redirect URI in the web.config of your application.

Comment: I actually wrote an article explaining this in greater detail. https://medium.com/@marilee.turscak/reply-urls-vs-postlogoutredirecturis-in-azure-active-directory-aad-20f57a03267b

Here's some official documentation that also delves into this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#basics-of-registering-an-application-in-azure-ad